# iOS navigation bar bottom line is missing

Tags: ios

I makes the navigation bar completely transparent by adding the following codes in viewWillAppear:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
```

Before the current view disappear, I reset the navigation bar by doing this in the viewDidDisappear method:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
```

but it turns out the little bottom line of the navigation bar is missing, here is the image that shows the normal navigation bar:

[image]

but it turns out being like this:

[image]

any idea about what is going on? and any solutions?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's missing because you set shadow image to nil. To fix this, delete line below :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
```

Comment: is it fix your problem Bond?

Comment: no, it does not. The little line of navigation bar still does not show up

Comment: Bond, can you explain your app's storyboard, when and how it's happen? Also, I want to understand why you're using viewWillAppear/viewDidDisappear methods. Generally, we're using appDelegate ...didFinish... method to customise appearance for all controls (like navigation bar). After that, when we need to customise a specific View Controller, we're using viewDidLoad. Means; lets say you're in main(root)View controller and push another controller but this one will be transparent. For this you need to use viewDidLoad for both view Controllers. And reset everything for your needs. Please try this.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I will try it. In fact, I am relatively new to iOS programming. and this is my second project. But I am still very grateful. Why my situation happened maybe has something to do with the way I do storyboard. I selected a navigation controller application so that the two views were already set up for me, one is table view. But I don't want a table view controller to be the root controller of the navigation controller, so I deleted it, and dragged a plain UIView onto the storyboard and made my customised controller the root controller of the navigation controller.

Comment: deleting the above code is the incorrect answer. Actually the above code is used to make the bottom line visible.

Comment: Dear @Tibin Thomas, I answered in 2015, but I answered only Junbang's question. Not the all the related questions. And that fixed Junbang's issue. If you have a better answer feel free to share with us. Best.

Answer (score 2):

The navigation bar shadow is only visible when the content scroll view is scrolled a certain distance vertically.

The "content scroll view" is the key—it's the first subview in the controller's `view`. Starting with iOS 15 [you can set it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/3816781-setcontentscrollview) but otherwise, it's based on the order of subviews.

This is also the way that the navigation bar determines whether to display a large title below the navigation bar when large title is enabled.

Frustratingly, not only is this concept not documented by Apple, even the new methods they added *this year* provide no description or any text at all.